# Maven Problem Missing Artifact (jsf-api.jar)

Tags: java, maven-2, jsf-2

I installed M2Eclipse Plug-In for Eclipse. I'm not very experienced with maven. My Problem is that I can't download two Artifacts:

```
    13.07.10 08:53:30 MESZ: Build errors for test; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project test: Missing:
----------
1) com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.0-b13

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun.faces -DartifactId=jsf-api -Dversion=2.0.0-b13 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun.faces -DartifactId=jsf-api -Dversion=2.0.0-b13 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
   1) de.studi:Studentenportal:pom:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   2) com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.0-b13

2) com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.0-b13

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun.faces -DartifactId=jsf-impl -Dversion=2.0.0-b13 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun.faces -DartifactId=jsf-impl -Dversion=2.0.0-b13 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
   1) de.studi:Studentenportal:pom:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   2) com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.0-b13

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact: 
  de.studi:Studentenportal:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

Here is my POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Studentenportal Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF/JSTL/Facelets -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
   <finalName>test</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried it with several versions of JSF2 with no success.

---

I added following to my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But the problem is still there. Is there someting wrong with that?

---

Okay I got it! The project can be built. Unfortunately I don't know why. I didn't changed something :-)

Now I get only Warnings from Maven:

```
13.07.10 10:04:04 MESZ: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
13.07.10 10:03:42 MESZ: [WARN] Missing POM for com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.0
13.07.10 10:03:43 MESZ: Updating index central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
13.07.10 10:04:04 MESZ: [WARN] Missing POM for com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.0
13.07.10 10:04:04 MESZ: Unable to download Repository[d9d714e11cb097b3ffcec91cccc65d3e|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index]/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.0/jsf-api-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.0/jsf-api-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'a2477a115d96ab5bddd88400beb176eaf43816d7'; remote = '<!--' - RETRYING
13.07.10 10:04:25 MESZ: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '83e1d5e415a35d55de79ab2c9a79bdd3182aa48a'; remote = '<!--' - RETRYING
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.0/jsf-api-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.0/jsf-api-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: Downloaded http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0/jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'b912ac4338d2bd37982d2d887fb82ac8fc5d54a2'; remote = '<!--' - IGNORING
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: [WARN] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '5e645760133f915dbc0da3d16edd304fdf8e8113'; remote = '<!--' - IGNORING
13.07.10 10:04:26 MESZ: Maven Builder: FULL_BUILD requireFullBuild
13.07.10 10:04:28 MESZ: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
13.07.10 10:04:28 MESZ: [INFO] Copying 0 resource
13.07.10 10:04:28 MESZ: [INFO] No sources to compile
13.07.10 10:04:28 MESZ: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
13.07.10 10:04:28 MESZ: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\StudiPortal\Workspaces\Studentenportal\src\test\resources
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: Refreshing [/Studentenportal/pom.xml]
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD requireFullBuild
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: [INFO] Copying 0 resource
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: [INFO] No sources to compile
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: [WARN] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
13.07.10 10:05:05 MESZ: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\StudiPortal\Workspaces\Studentenportal\src\test\resources
```

It doesn't look so good -.- Especially the Missing POM warnings are anxious.

---

### Update

First I changed it to myfaces and then I added the appropriate repository to the settings.xml in the .m2 directory. Like that:

```
<profile>
  <id>jdk-1.6</id>

  <activation>
    <jdk>1.6</jdk>
  </activation>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>JBOSS</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

But there is still the problem that maven can't find the artifacts. Pls help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your groupId's dependency is wrong. Enter [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com) and look for your dependencies there.

com.sun.faces should be javax.faces (version number might be wrong too)

If you got that dependency from some blog or web page try to find out from where is it downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have, neither in your `pom.xml` and its parent, nor in your `settings.xml` defined a list of maven repositories allowing you to access to these artifacts.

Typically, when encountering that kind of issue, my first move is to go check on [mvnbrowser](http://www.mvnbrowser.com) where are the artifacts availables. In the case of `jsf-api`, the reply is [quite simple](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=com.sun.faces&artifactId=jsf-api&version=2.0.0-b13&tab=REPOSITORIES#tabs) : you have to add JavaNet repository to your pom.xml [repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).